# How to find source of arithmetic error in IDL program?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am debugging an existing program which appears to fail due to various arithmetic errors.

> Program caused arithmetic error: Floating divide by 0

Is there a way to find out what part of the program is producing these errors? Or make the IDL development environment stop when one of these is raised?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [!EXCEPT system variable](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/error_handling_system_va.html#EXCEPT) to 2 will print errors for each statement, showing what file and which line caused the error.

```
!EXCEPT = 2
```

> % Program caused arithmetic error: Floating divide by 0
>
> % Detected at FUNCTION          77 /home/user/function.pro

The [documentation on CHECK_MATH](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/CHECK_MATH.html) provides more information about how arithmetic errors are handled, in addition to the [documentation on math error handling](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Math_Errors.html) in general.